# My questions are upvoted, but there's no increase of my reputation

Tags: support, reputation

During the last day, my answers were upvoted at least 10 times without any increase of my reputation. 10×10=100 points is what I'm missing. I don't need those points, I need to know what's going on, why is it, and if it is OK on this site to be like that. Have a look at my [profile reputation statistics](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/66/yellow-sky?tab=reputation):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hit the [reputation cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it) of 200 points per day.

The only exceptions (that may make it over 200 points) are:

- awarded bounties
- 15 pts for accepted your answers
- 2 pts for your accepting someone's answer (I believe)
- 2 pts for edits (I believe), but this no longer applies to you since you've already received the *Edit privilege*

Comment: Ouch! I never knew about that. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: However hitting the 200 exp cap you earned Mortarboard bronze badge and now you can go for Epic and Legendary badges.